# Vaadin add Grid in table

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have the following code:

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 3);
grid.addComponent(btnRemove, 0, 0);
grid.addComponent(lblIstMenge, 1, 0);
grid.addComponent(btnAdd, 2, 0);
int i = 0;
if (vList != null && vList.size() > 0)
{
    for (VTr component : vList)
    {
        String transactionTypeName = component.getTransactionTypeName();
        transaktionTable.addItem(new Object[]{++transaktionTableCounter + "", 
          transactionTypeName,
          "123123123123123", grid, "Bemerkung^^^"}, 
          transaktionTableCounter);
        // System.out.println("Grid: " + grids.get(i));
      }
}
```

Which gives me something like this:

[image: Example of grid]

***So the grid is added only in the last column.  I have tried creating different grids for each column in a list but this did not work for me.***

If you have any ideas or recommendations it would be nice.

Comment: In the "scene graph" of Vaadin, components have a parent.  So if you add you component to some sort of container it will happily accept it and the parent gets changed for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I move the instantiation of the buttons and grids inside the for loop it is working as expected.

```
                    int i = 0;
                    if (vList != null && vList.size() > 0)
                    {
                        for (VTr component : vList)
                        {

   btnAdd = new Button();
   btnAdd.setIcon(new ThemeResource("images/btnIncrease.png"));
                            btnRemove = new Button();
                            btnRemove.setIcon(new ThemeResource("images/btnDescrease.png"));
     GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 3);
                    grid.addComponent(btnRemove, 0, 0);
                    grid.addComponent(lblIstMenge, 1, 0);
                    grid.addComponent(btnAdd, 2, 0);        
                            String transactionTypeName = component.getTransactionTypeName();
                            transaktionTable.addItem(new Object[]{++transaktionTableCounter + "", transactionTypeName,
                                "123123123123123", grid, "Bemerkung^^^"}, transaktionTableCounter);

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: That's because as @cfrick was trying to explain, a component can have only one parent. So you can not add the same grid layout and buttons to multiple cells. Instead, if you create new instances, you won't have any issues.